# Count Unique Values with Conditions Excel

Tags: arrays, excel

I'm trying to create a simple chart to show how many employees are on a given corrective action level within a specified date range. The issue I'm running into is this:

The log shows associate Test 1 received a verbal warning on 8/14/19 for their productivity, then a first written warning on 8/24/19, then a final written warning that was processed later but took place on 8/23/19.

The formula I wrote will show this as 1 person at each level of correction (verbal, first written, and final written). I want it to only count the highest-level warning for each person. So the chart would only count 1 entry at the final written warning level.

What am I missing to accomplish this?

Raw Data:

[image]

Summary Chart:

[image]

Summary Chart Formula (across from Verbal level):

```
={SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(('2019'!$C:$C<>"")*('2019'!$F:$F=$B$2)*('2019'!$D:$D>=$B$3)*('2019'!$D:$D<=$C$3)*('2019'!$E:$E=$B5)*('2019'!$E:$E<>$B6),MATCH('2019'!$C:$C,'2019'!$C:$C,0)),ROW('2019'!$C:$C)-ROW('2019'!$C$2)+1)>0))}''''
```

Comment: Nothing is jumping out to me, you may need a helper column to indicate which is the highest level and then include that in your formula.

Comment: @Scott Craner What would that look like for this type of formula? I don't want to over-complicate it for the end user on our HR team

Comment: What version of Excel? Can you provide a table as text which can be copied into a worksheet,perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), that includes multiple employees.

Answer (score 2):

Cracked it! I added two helper columns to the raw data in between Step and Reason.

The first, Level, is a VLOOKUP that converts the Step to a numerical value (in order of severity, the lowest being a Verbal, highest being an Exit).

The second, Max, is a MAXIFS formula to flag which step is the highest severity by associate ID and Reason:

```
=IF(MAXIFS(F:F,C:C,C2,H:H,H2,D:D,">="&Summary!$B$3,D:D,"<="&Summary!$C$3)=F2,"X","")
```

[image]

The formula in the summary chart now reads as follows:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(('2019'!$C:$C<>"")*('2019'!$I:$I=$B$2)*('2019'!$D:$D>=$B$3)*('2019'!$D:$D<=$C$3)*('2019'!$F:$F=$B5)*('2019'!$H:$H="X"),MATCH('2019'!$C:$C,'2019'!$C:$C,0)),ROW('2019'!$C:$C)-ROW('2019'!$C$1)+1)>0))
```